# how to pass string variable as globbing argument to command

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory with some tif files I want to merge together depending on file suffixes (note the spaces in the file names):

```
File1 P1.tif
File1 P2.tif
File1 P3.tif
File2 P1.tif
File2 P2.tif
```

should result in merged tifs:

```
File1.tif
File2.tif
```

I have

```
for i in *\ P1.tif; do
    match=${i/\ P1/\ P*}
    out=${i/\ P1/}
    echo "processing $match"
    tiffcp "$match" "$out"
done
```

`$match` will contain `File1 P*.tif` and `$out` will contain `File1.tif`. but tiffcp will handle the first argument as a string and won't find a matching file. if a do not use quotes around `$match` the spaces in the file names will result in no matching file

so the question is: how do I pass a globbing string as an argument to a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want globbing to be performed upon parameter expansion (which by the way is performed by the shell, prior to calling the command; the command sees the resulting files, not the pattern), that's where you'd leave the parameter expansion unquoted.

Leaving a parameter expansion unquoted implies both word splitting and globbing (sometimes referred to as a conceptual split+glob operator). Here, you only want the globbing part, so you'd need to disable the splitting part (by assigning an empty value to the special `$IFS` variable):

```bash
IFS= # disable splitting
for i in ./*\ P1.tif; do
    match=${i/\ P1/\ P*}
    out=${i/\ P1/}
    echo "processing $match"
    tiffcp $match "$out" # split+glob on $match
done
```

That assumes the leading part of the file name doesn't contain wildcard characters. Alternatively, you could do:

```bash
for i in ./*\ P1.tif; do
    prefix=${i%\ P1.tif}
    out=$prefix.tif
    echo "processing $prefix"
    tiffcp "$prefix P"*.tif "$out"
done
```

That way, only that `*` is taken as a glob operator, and that code also has the advantage of only using standard sh syntax.

Note that glob expansions are sorted lexically, so P10 would come before P2. Use `zsh` and its `numericglobsort` option (or `n` glob qualifier) for numeric sorting.